# Filtering a nested list by select a list that have minimum value after determine the lists that have first priority?

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter, nested-lists

I need to select the list that has a minimum value for each unique name after specifying the lists that have first priority for example

The original nested list:

```
lst=[[['ahmad','a',5],['ahmad','a',6],['ahmad','c',4],['Emme','b',5],['Emme','b',4]],[['ahmad','b',5],['ahmad','b',6],['ahmad','c',6],['ahmad','c',5],['Meno','c',4],['Emme','b',5],['Moo','b',4],['Moo','a',7],['Moo','a',5]]]
```

Each list is expressed as: `['name', 'priority term', value]`.

The priority is for 'a' then 'b' and then 'c'.

The desired result:

```
new_lst=[[['ahmad','a',5],['Emme','b',4]],[['ahmad','b',5],['Meno','c',4],['Emme','b',5],['Moo','a',5]]]
```

**Update:**

If the list :

```
lst=[[['ahmad','red',5,20,'a'],['ahmad','red',6,21,'a'],['ahmad','blue',4,15,'c'],['Emme','red',5,30,'b'],['Emme','red',4,12,'b']],[['ahmad','blue',5,10,'b'],['ahmad','blue',6,13,'b'],['ahmad','blue',6,15,'c'],['ahmad','blue',5,30,'c'],['Meno','green',4,40,'c'],['Emme','green',5,35,'b'],['Moo','red',4,7,'b'],['Moo','red',7,3,'a'],['Moo','red',5,18,'a']]]
```

Each list is expressed as: `['name','color',value, trivial number, 'priority term']`.

the desired result:

```
new_list=[[['ahmad','red',5,20,'a'],['ahmad','blue',4,15,'c'],['Emme','red',4,12,'b']],[['ahmad','blue',5,10,'b'],['Meno','green',4,40,'c'],['Emme','green',5,35,'b'],['Moo','red',5,18,'a']]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to hold your prioritization order. Then use `sorted` followed by `toolz.unique` to sort and drop duplicate names:

```
from toolz import unique

priority = {v: k for k, v in enumerate('abc')}

def prioritiser(x):
    return priority[x[1]], x[2]

res = [list(unique(sorted(sublist, key=prioritiser), key=lambda x: x[0])) \
       for sublist in lst]

print(res)

[[['ahmad', 'a', 5], ['Emme', 'b', 4]],
 [['Moo', 'a', 5], ['ahmad', 'b', 5], ['Emme', 'b', 5], ['Meno', 'c', 4]]]
```

If you don't have access to the 3rd party [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), note that the function is identical to the `itertools` `unique_everseen` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: 'thank you for your  effort, I tried your method but i get this error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-387-71db320f41d1> in <module>()
      4 from toolz import unique
      5 
----> 6 priority = {v: k for k, v in dict(enumerate(list('abc'))).items()}
      7 
      8 def prioritiser(x):

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable '

Comment: Have you defined `list` as a variable in your code beforehand? If so, please rename it so it doesn't conflict with built-ins, e.g. `lst` or `L` instead of `list`.